# How do you get the "this" of a function?

Tags: javascript, function, this

How do you get the `this` value of a function from outside the function, without having to call it? For example, the following doesn't work, but illustrates the idea:

```
// window is this, currently
function foo() {}
console.log(foo.this) // would log the window object.
```

The MDN documentation for [Function.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) reports that `bind()` "creates a new function that, when called, has its this keyword set to the provided value". This implies that each function has a "this" associated with it from the ery start.

The question is whether or not that "this" is accessible from outside the function call, because presumably it's "this" reference already exists based on thos MDN docs.

Try this in your console:

```
var foo = function() {}
var bar = foo.bind(this)
console.log(foo === bar)
```

The result is `false`, meaning you now have two functions, not one, and each one has it's own `this`.

Some have mentioned that the "callsite" determines the `this` of a function, which doesn't seem to be true. If you run

```
var obj = {}
function foo() {
  console.log(this)
}
function Obj(func) {
  console.log(this)
  func()
}
new Obj(foo)
```

Then the callsite for foo is inside a `new Obj` but it still logs the `Window` object.

If you run

```
var obj = {}
function foo() {
  console.log(this)
}
foo()
foo.call(obj)
foo.bind(obj)
foo()
```

Then you'll notice that the `this` of the original foo function has not changed. Based on this fact, and the MDN docs for `bind`, `call`, and `apply`, we can confidently assume that the `this` for a Function can never be changed.

Comment: `console.log(foo);` ?

Comment: You don't get this from outside the function without calling it. Tell us what you'd like to do with it

Comment: There is no such thing.  `this` is only set based on the call site.

Comment: *"window is this, currently"* No it's not. The value of `this` depends on how the function is **called**.

Comment: @SLaks I think you might be wrong. The MDN documentation for [Function.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) reports that bind() "creates new function" that is bound to it's new "this". This implies that each function has a "this" associated with it. Whether or not that is accessible is the question. Try this in your console: `var foo = function() {}; var bar = foo.bind(this); console.log(foo === bar)`. The result is false.

Comment: @FelixKling Are you sure? Please see my previous comment.

Comment: Yep, bind is the exception. However, that was not addressed in your original question. And no,  it's not accessible either way.

Comment: @FelixKling: I made that comment before he mentioned `bind` at all.

Comment: @SLaks It doesn't even matter if I mentioned `bind`. The docs imply that a function *does* have a `this` no matter what the call site is. The docs for `call` and `apply` also imply the `this` of a function is set the moment it is defined, and it doesn't ever change.

Comment: @SLaks For example, try running `var obj = {};
function foo() {console.log(this)};
foo();
foo.call(obj);
foo()` and you'll see foo still has the same `this` in the end.

Comment: @trusktr: A function always has a `this`, and that `this` is always set based on the callsite.  `bind()` actually just wraps the bound function, so that the callsite is within `bind()` itself.

Comment: @trusktr: And, wrong; that will log two different objects.  `foo()` will pass  the global object as `this`.

Comment: @SLaks The `this` doesn't seem to change based on the callsite. For example, run this: `var obj = {};
function foo() {console.log(this)};

function Obj(func) {
 console.log(this);
 func();
}
new Obj(foo);` and you will see that the callsite for foo is inside the new Obj, but it still logs `Window`, which means the new callsite doesn't change foo's "this".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69977/discussion-between-trusktr-and-slaks).

Comment: I recommend to read the [MND documentation about `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Comment: *"Then you'll notice that the this of the original foo function has not changed."* `foo()` and `foo.call(obj)` should produce two different outputs.

Comment: @FelixKling Yes, it does, but it has not changed foo's "this", because after that you can call foo again, and it reports the original this from where it was originally defined.

Comment: OK, you can't seem to be convinced otherwise, so lets assume the `this` value is indeed be set on function definition. How would you define a function whose `this` value does not refer to `window`?

Comment: @trusktr: **`foo` doesn't _have_ a `this`**.  `foo()` passes `window` (the global object) as `this`; nothing is stored anywhere.

Comment: Please see my answer. If you don't believe our comments, maybe you believe the language specification.

Comment: Thanks a ton guys! I've learned. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is no way to get the value of `this` because `this` is not actually related to the function object, but to the **execution context** that is created when the function is called.

An [**execution context**](http://es5.github.io/#x10.3) has the following properties:

> **LexicalEnvironment**
>   Identifies the Lexical Environment used to resolve identifier references made by code within this execution context.
>
> **VariableEnvironment**
>   Identifies the Lexical Environment whose environment record holds bindings created by VariableStatements and FunctionDeclarations within this execution context.
>
> **ThisBinding**
>   The value associated with the `this` keyword within ECMAScript code associated with this execution context.

Now, when a function is **called**, [the following steps take place](http://es5.github.io/#x10.4.3):

> [**10.4.3 Entering Function Code**](http://es5.github.io/#x10.4.3)
>   The following steps are performed when control enters the execution context for function code contained in function object *F*, a caller provided *thisArg*, and a caller provided *argumentsList*:
>
> 1. If the [function code](http://es5.github.io/#function-code) is [strict code](http://es5.github.io/#x10.1.1), set the ThisBinding to *thisArg*.
> 2. Else if *thisArg* is **null** or **undefined**, set the ThisBinding to the [global object](http://es5.github.io/#x15.1).
> 3. Else if Type(*thisArg*) is not Object, set the ThisBinding to ToObject(*thisArg*).
> 4. Else set the ThisBinding to *thisArg*.
> 5. Let *localEnv* be the result of calling [NewDeclarativeEnvironment](http://es5.github.io/#x10.2.2.2) passing the value of the [[Scope]] internal property of *F* as the argument.
> 6. Set the LexicalEnvironment to *localEnv*.
> 7. Set the VariableEnvironment to *localEnv*.
> 8. Let *code* be the value of *F*’s [[Code]] internal property.
> 9. Perform Declaration Binding Instantiation using the [function code](http://es5.github.io/#function-code) *code* and *argumentList* as described in [10.5](http://es5.github.io/#x10.5).

Notice especially

> [...] a caller provided *thisArg* [...]

This should make clear that the value of `this` is provided by the **caller of the function**.

Examples:

When a function is called as `foo()`, then there is no `thisArg`, so it is `undefined`. In that case, step 2 takes place and `this` is bound to the global object.

However, if a function is called as `foo.call(bar)`, then `thisArg` is `bar` and either step 3 or 4 take place, depending on whether `bar` is an object or not.

I hope this explains why it is not possible to get the `this` value of a function.

Comment: So when strict mode isn't specified, only then does the callsite matter, so that if the function isn't attached to an object, it get the global object as "this"? But with strict mode enabled, then the callsite is irrelevant and the only thing that determines what "this" of a function will be is what object it's assigned on?

Comment: Regarding `this`, the only difference between strict mode and non-strict mode is what `this` refers to when the function is called "normally", i.e. like `foo()`. In non-strict node, `this` will point to the global object, in strict mode it will be `undefined`. All other ways (i.e. `obj.foo()`, `foo.call(...)`, `foo.apply(..)`, `new foo()`) are not affected. *"the only thing that determines what "this" of a function will be is what object it's assigned on"* Calling a function as an object method is only *one* way of calling a function. Every way affects the value of `this`.

Comment: Ah, i see, so it's not really the callsite (the location in code) that matters, but just which object (if any) that you call it on, e.g. a.foo(), b.foo(), foo() where foo in each example is a reference to the same function, but each one has a different this.

Comment: Yes. And `new foo()`, `foo.call(thisObj)`, `foo.apply(thisObj)`, as I already mentioned.

Comment: Have I misinterpreted "callsite"? Is callsite the "object on which the function is called on" rather than the "location in your code where the function gets called"?

Comment: Nope, callsite means "location in your code where the function gets called".

Answer (score 3):

*this* can be changed depending on how you call the function, so, there is no real way to get it outside of the function.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Comment: Also good to note that you can set the 'this' using foo.bind(myThis) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: Too bad you can't do `foo.getThis()` or similar.

Comment: Again, this can be different depending on how you call the function.  It could be one thing at one point in your code, and a totally different thing at another time.  How would that work?

Answer (score -1):

you need a little help from the function.

```
function foo(){
    return this;
};
console.log(foo());
```

Comment: How exactly does that work if the function isn't called?

Comment: As my question states, without calling it. The function might be called who knows where, in some other scope I have no access to. I might be passing it as a callback to something, but I'd like to know it's "this" value before passing it along.